# Line Break Height in android

Tags: java, android, textview

Now I am having a code which counts the height and width of a paragraph and sets it accordingly. However I have been having this strange problems whenever a break line(\n) passes through my paragraph I use this code to calculate my Height. I also calculate the width and make sure a line is properly fit.

```
float textSize = t.getTextSize();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(textSize);
```

However for some reason a break line couldn't have the height calculated which would mean me missing a few lines or show me half a line cause of the break lines during my performed calculations.

My question is, how would I undergo the calculation of the height of a break line of the space it occupies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this issue. However I did try to just delete 3 more extra characters at the edge of the end point of the width. It worked. However the real problem lies more in the character width. If a character is not registered with android a calculation vs the actual out come can be very different if you have letters that are completely different that off the regular alphabet.

Using this code you can determine the edge of the endpoint.

```
totalCurrentWidth = t.getPaint().measureText(s.substring(start, end));
```

However characters not registered in the system may have a different end or no end at all(Chinese or taiwan for example).

During each individual characters used in verdana it produces a different spacing compared to the actual outcome of the text.

If anyone find something wrong with my logic feel free to comment me. I only strive to improve after all.